# Almost sure convergence for sequence of non-increasing non-negative random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

So, I'm trying to prove the following lemma.

> $X_1, X_2, \dots$ random variables, $X_t \geq X_{t+1}, X_t \geq 0, c > 0$.
>   Assume that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\gamma >0$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} \leq X_t - \gamma\epsilon) > c$ whenever $X_t > \epsilon$. Then $X_t \rightarrow 0$ almost surely.

My first thought was the Borel-Cantelli lemmas. I don't see how I can get independent events for using the second lemma though, given that the random variables aren't independent. I also don't see how to apply the first lemma here; that "whenever $X_t > \epsilon$" throws me off.

Since we don't know anything about expected value or variance, I also don't see how to use any of the standard inequalities. Or can we draw some kind of conclusion about this simply from $X_n$ being non-increasing and non-negative?

This is part of a hand-in, so ideally I'd just like a hint to point me in the right direction. Much obliged if anyone has one.

Comment: Maybe what is meant is $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1} \leq X_t - \gamma\epsilon \mid X_t\gt \epsilon) > c$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you, but I'm still having problems. Ideally I'd want to say that the probability that $X_n$ decreases at any given step is constant, so $A_n = \{ X_{n + 1} < X_n \}$ are independent events, then apply the second B-C lemma... but I guess this isn't true. Do I need to fix an $\epsilon$ and use the first B-C lemma somehow?